# Email field disappears when radio button unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding validation for my form. The error messages for the email and the radio button work fine, but if you don't check the radio button and try to submit the form, the email field disappears. Can someone help me fix it?

I don't think my CSS has anything to do with it, because this problem didn't pop up until after I added the error message for the radio button.

```js
function validateForm() { //creates function for validation
  var email = document.forms["emailForm"]["email"].value; //calls form to be validated
  if (email == "") { //if email is left blank

    document.getElementById('emailerr').style.visibility = "visible"; //make error message visible
    document.getElementById('emailerr').innerHTML = "*Valid email address required"; //error message
    return false; //does not submit form
  } else {
    document.getElementById('email').style.visibility = "hidden"; //hides error message
  }

  if (document.emailForm.age.checked == false) { //if you haven't verified you're 18+

    document.getElementById('18err').style.visibility = "visible"; //make error message visible
    document.getElementById('18err').innerHTML = "*Please verify you are over 18"; //error message
    return false; //does not submit form
  } else {
    document.getElementById('18err').style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="emailForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div id="emailerr"></div>

  <label for="update">
      <input type="checkbox" value="update" id="update">
      I want coupons<br>
     </label>

  <label for="new">
      <input type="checkbox" value="new" id="new">
      I want updates on new plants<br>
     </label>

  <label for="update">
      <input type="checkbox" value="update" id="update">
      Include me on other plant info<br>
     </label>

  <label for="age" id="verify">
      <input type="radio" id="age">
      I verify I am 18 years or older.
     </label>
  <div id="18err"></div>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: normally input is outside the label. Fix that and I am not able to replicate your problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the else part of the first if condition within the `validateForm()` method. In the else part -- if the email field is not empty you are setting the visibility of `#email` as hidden, instead you should set the visibility of `#emailerr` as hidden.

Please try changing the value in getElementByID from `email` to `emailerr`. I have made the required changes in the below snippet. Hope this will help!!

```js
function validateForm() { //creates function for validation
  var email = document.forms["emailForm"]["email"].value; //calls form to be validated
  if (email == "") { //if email is left blank

    document.getElementById('emailerr').style.visibility = "visible"; //make error message visible
    document.getElementById('emailerr').innerHTML = "*Valid email address required"; //error message
    return false; //does not submit form
  } else {
    document.getElementById('emailerr').style.visibility = "hidden"; //hides error message
  }

  if (document.emailForm.age.checked == false) { //if you haven't verified you're 18+

    document.getElementById('18err').style.visibility = "visible"; //make error message visible
    document.getElementById('18err').innerHTML = "*Please verify you are over 18"; //error message
    return false; //does not submit form
  } else {
    document.getElementById('18err').style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="emailForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div id="emailerr"></div>

  <label for="update">
      <input type="checkbox" value="update" id="update">
      I want coupons<br>
     </label>

  <label for="new">
      <input type="checkbox" value="new" id="new">
      I want updates on new plants<br>
     </label>

  <label for="update">
      <input type="checkbox" value="update" id="update">
      Include me on other plant info<br>
     </label>

  <label for="age" id="verify">
      <input type="radio" id="age">
      I verify I am 18 years or older.
     </label>
  <div id="18err"></div>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateForm() { //creates function for validation
  var email = document.forms["emailForm"]["email"].value; //calls form to be validated
  if (email == "") { //if email is left blank

    document.getElementById('emailerr').style.visibility = "visible"; //make error message visible
    document.getElementById('emailerr').innerHTML = "*Valid email address required"; //error message
    return false; //does not submit form
  } else {
    document.getElementById('emailerr').style.visibility = "hidden"; //hides error message
  }

  if (document.emailForm.age.checked == false) { //if you haven't verified you're 18+

    document.getElementById('18err').style.visibility = "visible"; //make error message visible
    document.getElementById('18err').innerHTML = "*Please verify you are over 18"; //error message
    return false; //does not submit form
  } else {
    document.getElementById('18err').style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

}
```

```html
   <form name="emailForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
   <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
   <div id="emailerr"></div>
   <label for="update">
   <input type="checkbox" value="update" id="update">
   I want coupons<br>
   </label>
   <label for="new">
   <input type="checkbox" value="new" id="new">
   I want updates on new plants<br>
   </label>
   <label for="update">
   <input type="checkbox" value="update" id="update">
   Include me on other plant info<br>
   </label>
   <label for="age" id="verify">
   <input type="radio" id="age">
   I verify I am 18 years or older.
   </label>
   <div id="18err"></div>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Else part(email validation whether it is empty or not) of your code you are hiding email input, please change that to email error id so that everything  works fine. Hope this helps

Your code:`document.getElementById('email').style.visibility = "hidden";`

Modified code:`document.getElementById('emailerr').style.visibility = "hidden";`